# When I send a request, I always get an error. React and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, request

I am new to IT, I started learning React and JS through video courses. When creating a site for a video course, I encountered a number of errors: when I try to send a request wrapped in a try catch, I always get an error. I don't understand why this is happening, please help.

**index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");


dotenv.config();

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.URL_MONGO, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log("Successfully connected"))
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });

app.use(express.json());

app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);


app.listen(8800, () => {
  console.log("Server is running!");
});
```

**User.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    profilePic: { type: String, defaut: "" },
    isAdmin: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
  
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

**auth.js**

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/User");


router.post("/registration", async (req, res) => {
  const newUser = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
  })

  try {
    const user = await newUser.save();
    res.status(201).json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

[Register request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swaL0.png)

[Second part Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mcuho.png)

Comment: You have a typo, in the `profilePic` definition for the `UserSchema`, it says `defaut` instead of `default`. Might not be the issue but it would cause problems.

Comment: Also, what happens when you log `req.body.username` etc... Do they have values?

Comment: I haven't connected this to the button yet. Is there some way to do it differently? I tried to write console.log(reg.body.username), but it seems to me that this way is wrong :/

Comment: On the backend, in the `auth.js` file, see what is coming in as the request (`req`) object.

Comment: I found an error, everything is correct in the code, in Postman the content-type was "text", instead of "JSON".

Answer (score 0):

For what I see on your img, you're doing a Netflix clone as I'm doing.

I can see that your request on postman is:

```json
{
 "username" = "eeqeqeqw",
 "email": "nova@gmail.com",
 "password":"2221"
}
```

So when working with objects, the values are asigned with ":" instead of "=" symbol.

Try to do the same request this way:

```json
{
 "username": "eeqeqeqw",
 "email": "nova@gmail.com",
 "password":"2221"
}
```

Comment: Oops, my mistake. Unfortunately it doesn't change anything :(( I watched the video many times at this stage, but I can not understand what could be the problem =(

Comment: Have you tried to change the default body in postman from "Text" to "Json"? This could cause the problem too.

Comment: I already solved the problem, in the comment above I answered.